# Handling back press in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Composable` which has different **views** *(see the code for better understanding)*
When user clicks on the button it navigates to different **view** but when user press the back button it navigates to previous **screen** but I want to navigate to pervious **view**
Something like on Back press `viewState` changes it's value
**Note: I don't found nice explanation than this**

```
var viewState by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column {
        when (viewState) {
            0 -> { Button(onClick = { viewState = 1 }) { Text(text = "Goto 1") } }
            1 -> { Button(onClick = { viewState = 2 }) { Text(text = "Goto 2") } }
            2 -> { Button(onClick = { viewState = 3 }) { Text(text = "Goto 3") } }
            3 -> { Button(onClick = { viewState = 4 }) { Text(text = "Goto 0") } }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation .. without using navigation also you can achieve the same thing but I recommend navigation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I got the answer** 
I have not added for `0` because it will execute `navController`

```
var viewState by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    when(viewState){
        1 -> BackHandler(enabled = true) {
            viewState = 0
        }
        2 -> BackHandler(enabled = true) {
            viewState = 1
        }
        3 -> BackHandler(enabled = true) {
            viewState = 2
        }
    }
    Column {
        val nextViewState = (viewState + 1) % 4
        Button(onClick = { viewState = nextViewState }) {
            Text(text = "Goto $nextViewState")
        }
    }
```

And the `function`

**EDIT**: `BackHandler` is a system function

Comment: `BackHandler` is a system function, no need to include it source code in the answer. Also moving `when` inside a single `BackHandler` will be cleaner.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: Irrelevant source code has been removed from answer.